# How do I prevent from a feature to be cut from a tile in openlayers?

Tags: openlayers-2

I have a map with GeoJSON layer.
I draw features on zoom 18 of OSM base layer.
When I zoom out the feature is overlay by the map tile
How can I enforce the feature to be on top of the tiles ?

[image]

```
<head runat="server">
<title>Map View</title>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.6&amp;sensor=false"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://openlayers.org/dev/OpenLayers.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/dev/theme/default/style.css" type="text/css">
<link href="Scripts/theme/default/MapView.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<telerik:RadCodeBlock ID="RadCodeBlock1" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var lon = 34.8458300,
        lat = 32.0311100,
        zoom = 14,
        map, layer, data, vector, tmpContent, toggleMode, iHandler, popup, highlightCtrl, geojson_layer, ttt,
        epsg4326 = new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:4326'),
        epsg900913 = new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:900913');

        lon = 34.8020;
        lat = 31.280;

        function init() {

            var myStyles = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
                "default": new OpenLayers.Style({
                    pointRadius: "10", // sized according to type attribute
                    fillColor: "#ffcc66",
                    strokeColor: "#ff9933",
                    strokeWidth: 2,
                    graphicZIndex: 1
                }),
                "select": new OpenLayers.Style({
                    fillColor: "#66ccff",
                    strokeColor: "#3399ff",
                    graphicZIndex: 2
                })
            });

            map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {
                units: 'm',
                numZoomLevels: 19,
                controls: [
                new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.ScaleLine(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher()
            ],
                projection: epsg900913,
                displayProjection: epsg4326 //Is used for displaying coordinates in appropriate CRS by MousePosition control
            });

            var lGoogle = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google('Google Sat', {
                type: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
                sphericalMercator: true
            });

            var lOSM = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google('Google');
            layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("OSM");
            vector = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector('Points', { styleMap: myStyles });

            geojson_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Features", {
                styleMap: myStyles,
                projection: epsg4326,
                strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
                protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                    url: "data/GPSData.txt",
                    format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
                })
            });

            map.addLayers([layer, lOSM, lGoogle, geojson_layer]);

            highlightCtrl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(geojson_layer, { hover: true });
            highlightCtrl.events.register('featurehighlighted', null, onFeatureHighlighted);

            map.addControl(highlightCtrl);
            highlightCtrl.activate();

            drawData();
            window.setInterval(drawData, 10000);

            map.setCenter(
            new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat).transform(
                new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
                map.getProjectionObject()
            ), zoom);
        }

        function onFeatureHighlighted(evt) {
            // Needed only for interaction, not for the display.
            var onPopupClose = function (evt) {
                // 'this' is the popup.
                var feature = this.feature;
                if (feature.layer) {
                    highlightCtrl.unselect(feature);
                }
                this.destroy();
            }

            feature = evt.feature;
            popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("featurePopup",
            feature.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat(),
            new OpenLayers.Size(100, 100),
            "<h3>" + feature.attributes.name + "</h3>" +
            "Date & Time: " + feature.attributes.datetime,
            null, true, onPopupClose);
            feature.popup = popup;
            popup.feature = feature;
            map.addPopup(popup, true);
        }

        function drawData() {

            geojson_layer.refresh({ force: true, params: { 'key': Math.random()} });
            Service.GetItemsFromFile(updateGrid);
        }

        function updateGrid(result) {
            var tableView = $find("<%= RadGrid1.ClientID %>").get_masterTableView();
            tableView.set_dataSource(result);
            tableView.dataBind();
        }           

        function onFeatureSelect(feature) {
            popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(
            feature.attributes.name,
            feature.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat(),
            null,
            "<div style='font-size:.8em; font-weight: bold'>" +
            feature.attributes.name + " - "
            + feature.attributes.datetime + "</div>",
            null,
            null,
            null
    );
            feature.popup = popup;
            popup.feature = feature;
            map.addPopup(popup);
        }

        function radGrid_RowSelected(senger, args) {

            map.setCenter(
            new OpenLayers.LonLat(args.get_item().get_dataItem().Lon, args.get_item().get_dataItem().Lat).transform(
                new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
                map.getProjectionObject()
            ), 18
        );
        }
    </script>
</telerik:RadCodeBlock>
```

Comment: Really weird. Which OL version are you using? That can be a bug about z-index. Try to put an issue in the github project page.

Comment: maybe easier to answer if you add your code

Comment: I've updated my code , Using OL 2.13 Dev.

Comment: Currently since I couldn't resolve this problem, I've updated the layer to be single tiled. Will be happy if someone can tell me what is the problem and how to solve it.